# USB device on LXD container inaccessible when in privileged mode

Tags: usb, permissions, lxc, lxd

I have a USB device that I have passed through to a container using this command:

```
lxc config device add <container> <device> unix-char path=/dev/bus/usb/004/002 mode=0777
```

This works OK until I make the container privileged (which is a requirement for me) using this command:

```
lxc config set <container> security.privileged true
```

lsusb says "Couldn't open device"

Is this the correct procedure?
Let me know what information I need to provide to troubleshoot this.

system: Ubuntu 16.04
lxd: 2.0.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was solved by granting access to the USB device using the relevant cgroup entry on my container configuration. In summary what was needed for my device to work in a privileged container was doing:

```
lxc config edit <container>
```

to edit the container configuration and add:

```
config:
  raw.lxc: lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c XXX:* rwm
devices:
  some_device_name:
    mode: "0777"
    path: /dev/bus/usb/004/002
    type: unix-char
```

where XXX = the "major" part of the major:minor id found using ls -la /dev/bus/usb/004/002

Credits for this go to https://askubuntu.com/a/545802/671072